# Trouble understanding value vs Series in PineScript

Tags: series, pine-script

```
greenCandleCount=0
if close > open
    greenCandleCount := greenCandleCount+1
plot(greenCandleCount)
```

In the above example, `greenCandleCount` is a value in the first line. But, close and open are both Series of floats. So in line 3, `greenCandleCount` seems to get converted into series. Because the line 2 comparison operation seems to produce a Series of booleans. Somehow a single variable lying inside an if block where the expression is a Series, also gets expanded into a Series. So why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

`greenCandleCount` doesn't get converted to series. The way you've declared it, it was always a series variable. At the start of the next bar, `greenCandleCount` would be reset to 0

With the code you've provided, `greenCandleCount` would always be either 1 or 0 and you'd be able to reference the previous bar's `greenCandleCount` state the same as any other series variable ie `greenCandleCount[1]`

If you wish to have a variable that is only initialized once and maintains it's value across bars it must be declared with the `var` keyword ie

`var greenCandleCount = 0`

Then your code will count the number of green candles on the entire chart.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_var

Comment: So any identifier set to a literal value without the use of the var keyword is a Series ?

Comment: Yes, you're just initializing the series variable for each bar without the var keyword